# How to edit Hugo content files directly in content root folder

Tags: netlify, hugo, netlify-cms

I am new to netlify and netlifyCMS. Did upload a Hugo site which is working well. Now trying to implement CMS. It is a very simple site with only a few *.md content files located directly in the root of the /content folder. How do I need to configure the config.yml so that I can edit them? I did only find how to edit collections in subfolders of  /content or single files.

Thank you
Best regards

Comment: Hola Manuel, Look, I think you just need to read the netlifyCMS docs - they are pretty clear on how to do this. Then if you have a specific point of resolution then you should ask the question, but this is just "make me a custom tutorial other than the 100's that already exist". Go to netlify CMS's site and check that out first...

Comment: Yes, I did read the docs, but I do only find how to define collections (which are in subfolders) or singe files.

Comment: Great, then edit the above post so that it's a specific question, even if the specific point you didn't understand on the docs, and then I, possibly we, can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did find a solution. Did add every content-file as a single file.

```
collections: # A list of collections the CMS should be able to edit
  - label: "Inhalt"
    name: "inhalt"
    files: 
      - label: "Home"
        name: "home"
        file: "/content/home.md"
        fields: # The fields each document in this collection have
          - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
          - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
      - label: "TCM"
        name: "tcm"
        file: "/content/tcm.md"
        fields: # The fields each document in this collection have
          - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
          - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
      - label: "Psycho"
        name: "psycho"
        file: "/content/psycho.md"
        fields: # The fields each document in this collection have
          - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
          - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```